# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function - Nested Functions & Environments

Tags: r

The R code shown below is a minimal working example to reproduce an error that I can't say I understand. Running the script should yield the error, `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "fitModel"`. After reading a thing or two on [environments](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) I think I understand why this is happening in this case, "fitModel" is not defined in the execution environment of "obscureFunction". This I fixed by making the following change to "myFormula": 
`myFormula <- "y ~ eval(fitModel(x, a), envir = environment(fitModel))"`

I don't understand how "fitModel" can be evaluated in the environment of "fitModel" when the function can't be found in the calling environment of "obscureFunction", in other words I don't understand why this code change works. I also don't understand why the original code works fine if the body of "topFunction" is run without calling it, i.e. if we define "fitModel" and "obscureFunction" in `R_GlobalEnv` and call "obscureFunction" from the console.

```
## Minimum Working Example to reproduce error
rm(list = ls())
library(minpack.lm)

topFunction <- function(){

       fitModel <- function(x, a){
              exp(-a * x)
       }

       ## Create a function to use with lapply()
       obscureFunction <- function(){

              x <- seq(-1, 1, 0.01)
              y <- exp(-0.5 * x)
              Data <- data.frame(x, y)

              init      <- c(a = 1)
              myFormula <- "y ~ fitModel(x, a)"
              myFormula <- as.formula(myFormula)
              nlsOutput <- nlsLM(formula = myFormula, start = init, data = Data)

              return(nlsOutput)

       }

       ## Function call
       obscureFunction()

       ## Other calculations done with fitModel()
} 

topFunction()
```

Comment: @BrodieG indeed. comment redacted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are two issues here. The first is using a string for a formula. It's better to use

```
myFormula <- y ~ fitModel(x, a)
```

The reason is that formulas capture their environment, strings do not. (As noted by @BridieG, the `as.formula()` will capture the environment; I skipped over that line when reading the code. I still think it's better to create the formula directly.) Having a reference environment makes it easier to find functions used in a formula. So if you were using `lm()` rather than `nlsLM`, this would work with these two changes

```
# myFormula <- "y ~ fitModel(x, a)"  ... becomes
myFormula <- y ~ fitModel(x, 1)

#nlsOutput <- nlsLM(formula = myFormula, start = init, data = Data) ...becomes
nlsOutput <- lm(formula = myFormula, data = Data)
```

This works with the formula syntax (unquoted var names) and not the string because the formula can capture the environment.

At least that's how it should work. Package authors are free to evaluate formulas how ever they want, and the authors of the `nlsLM()` function decided to ignore the environment assigned to the formula. They do so in this function inside `nlsLM()`

```
FCT <- function(par) {
    mf[m] <- par
    rhs <- eval(formula[[3L]], envir = mf)
    res <- lhs - rhs
    res <- .swts * res
    res
}
```

So this is the second problem. Here they enforce the evaluation in the `mf` object which is a data.frame made up of the covariates of the data and the parameter estimates. Had it been written as

```
rhs <- eval(formula[[3L]], envir = mf, environment(formula))
```

it would have worked. This is basically what `model.frame()` does in `lm()` that allows this to work. We can make our own "corrected" version of the function with

```
# tested with minpack.lm_1.1-8
nlsLM2<-nlsLM
body(nlsLM2)[[27]][[3]][[3]][[3]]<-quote(rhs<-eval(formula[[3L]], envir = mf, environment(formula)))
```

And then make these substitutions

```
# myFormula <- "y ~ fitModel(x, a)"  ... becomes
myFormula <- y ~ fitModel(x, a)

#nlsOutput <- nlsLM(formula = myFormula, start = init, data = Data) ...becomes
nlsOutput <- nlsLM2(formula = myFormula, start = init, data = Data)
```

it work work and return

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ fitModel(x, a)
   data: Data
  a 
0.5 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```

So there's not really much you can say about how all R functions handle environments and scope. This behavior is unique to how the `nlsLM()` authors decided to evaluate their parameters.

Comment: Note this works fine with the character formula followed by `as.formula`, as the second step attaches the environment (+1)

Comment: Good point @BrodieG. (but i still think it's better to skip that step and just make a proper formula in the first place).

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick, your solution works at my end as well. I also didn't think of creating modified versions of R functions, so now I get to play around with a few other modifications to nlsLM I've been wanting to try.